# How to install a newer version of Ruby than what is present in the package manager?

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm using "yum" which has a very old version of Ruby. I'm on linux OS and quite new to it. How can I install a specific version of Ruby that isn't present in the package installer?

Note: I don't have the other package managers (rbenv / rmv etc).

Note2: I am connected to this Linux machine via putty. So I only have command-line access.

Comment: rvm is designed to be installed without root permissions, provided that the packages needed to build Ruby are installed.  Why is rvm not available to you?

Comment: I have "yum" installed and not rvm. And I need to use an official image that is provided by my company. The official image provides yum which contains a Ruby version that is several years old. Why? There's never a clear answer when it comes to linux.

Answer (score 1):

Without package managers and using yum, your last option is to build from source.

> Building from Source
>
> Of course, you can install Ruby from source.
> Download and unpack a tarball (EG: [Ruby 3.0.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)), then just do this:
>
> `$ ./configure`
> `$ make`
> `$ sudo make install`
> By default, this will install
> Ruby into /usr/local. To change, pass the --prefix=DIR option to the
> ./configure script.

REF: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have seen this in Ruby's docs. Unfortunately, it doesn't tell how we can achieve this through Ruby's command line (I'm connected via Putty). It would be really great if you could suggest how to achieve those steps.

Comment: Download a package from the link (use wget from the command line and the url). Unpack it using tar, eg tar - xf downloaded-package-name.tar. Cd into the unpacked directory. Run the commands above.

Comment: I am trying these commands and it says "$ command not found". It would be great if this answer can be simplified further.

Comment: you're probably best to ask that as a different question. Or search for it.